# Is such a downcast safe?

Tags: c++

Suppose we have the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct BaseComponent
{
    template <typename T>
    T * as()
    {
        return static_cast<T*>(this);
    }

    virtual ~BaseComponent() {}
};

template <typename T>
struct Component : public BaseComponent
{
    virtual ~Component() {}
};

struct PositionComponent : public Component<PositionComponent>
{
    float x, y, z;

    virtual ~PositionComponent() {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseComponent>> mComponents;
    mComponents.emplace_back(new PositionComponent);

    auto *pos = mComponents[0]->as<PositionComponent>();
    pos->x = 1337;

    return 0;
}
```

---

In the T * as() method, should I use a static_cast or a dynamic_cast? are there times when the the conversion will fail? Do I need to dynamic_cast like this instead?

```
    auto *ptr = dynamic_cast<T*>(this);

    if(ptr == nullptr)
        throw std::runtime_error("D'oh!");

    return ptr;
```

Comment: That is usually called a **down**cast, not upcast.

Comment: What is the usage of your template argument T of the Component class?

Comment: @Reinhard: I guess you draw your hierarchies different than I (and most other people do), since for me the bases are up, and the derived types down... Note that the *natural* thing on a language is *whatever will be understood*. Some cultures point forward to the future, some point forward to the past, in each culture pointing in the wrong direction will cause confusion. When dealing with OO, the consensus is that up is towards the base, down towards the derived types

Comment: @Reinhard You might want to check out these entity-system libraries for C++: [anax](https://github.com/miguelishawt/anax) and [entityx](https://github.com/alecthomas/entityx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you present is correct and well formed, but the cast in general is not safe. If the actual object was not a `PositionComponent`, then the compiler would very gladly assume that it is and you would be causing undefined behavior.

If you replace the cast with `dynamic_cast`, then the compiler will generate code that at runtime verifies that the conversion is valid.

The real question is why would you need this. There are reasons, but more often than not the use of casts are an indication of issues with your design. Reconsider whether you can do *better* (i.e. redesign your code so that you don't need to go explicitly converting types)

Comment: Well I'm taking a look at how to implement an Entity-Component-System, an Entity is supposed to hold its components, so that's one solution. But it's ugly, I agree

Comment: @Reinhard: What do the components have in common, do they have a common interface? If so, just use it. There is no need to know what the particular component is if you can tell it what to do and it does it...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Components don't do anything; they are used to store data for entities.

Answer (score 3):

In your case there is no way to tell statically whether `this` is the right type or not.
What you may want is a CRTP (Curiously recurring template pattern):

```
template <class T>
struct BaseComponent
{
    T* as()
    {
        return static_cast<T*>(this);
    }

    virtual ~BaseComponent() {}
};

template <typename T>
struct Component : public BaseComponent<T>
{
    virtual ~Component() {}
};

struct PositionComponent : public Component<PositionComponent>
{
    float x, y, z;

    virtual ~PositionComponent() {}
};
```

This way you can do:

```
auto x = yourBaseComponent.as();
```

and have the right child type statically.

Comment: Yeah, but he didn't described what was the use of templates in his case. Hence my "what you MAY want".

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `unique_ptr<BaseComponent>`, naturally there could be times when the conversion fails: the insertion of new data in the vector and consumption of that data are done in unrelated places, and in such a way that the compiler cannot enforce it.

Here is an example of an invalid cast:

```
struct AnotherComponent : public Component<AnotherComponent>
{
    virtual ~AnotherComponent () {}
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseComponent>> mComponents;
mComponents.emplace_back(new AnotherComponent);
// !!! This code compiles, but it is fundamentally broken !!!
auto *pos = mComponents[0]->as<PositionComponent>();
pos->x = 1337;
```

In this respect, using `dynamic_cast` would provide better protection against incorrect usage of the `as<T>` function. Note that the incorrect usage may not be intentional: any time the compiler cannot check the type for you, and you have a potential type mismatch, you should prefer `dynamic_cast<T>`

Here is a [small demo](http://ideone.com/87DMco) to illustrate how `dynamic_cast` would offer you a degree of protection.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use `dynamic_cast` when casting polymorphic objects that are derived from a baseclass.

In a case where `mComponents[0]` is not `PositionComponent` (or a class derived therefrom), the above code would fail. Since the whole purpose of having `mComponents` hold a pointer to `BaseComponent` is so that you can put other things than `PositionComponent` objects into the vector, I'd say you need to care for that particular scenario.

In general, it's a "bad smell" when you are using `dynamic_cast` (or generally casting objects that are derived from a common baseclass). Typically it means the objects should not be held in a common container, because they are not closely enough related.

Comment: **"You should always use dynamic_cast when casting objects that are derived from a baseclass."**

Not unless you *know* the type. Also, dynamic_cast should only be used for polymorphic objects. Component could easily remove the virtual function and it would stil behave the same (assuming you are not using the destructor). And in entity-systems you typically do not need to use a destructor for components, as they are POD.